# Menu nav always present as a frame

Tags: jquery, navigation

Look at this site: 
http://genelab.nasa.gov/

You can change page (about.html, events.html) and div.site-column-left is always there.

I'd like to know how it's possible to have a div.site-column-left) always present when changing the page.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: you are not really changing the page, you use [Javascript AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to update a part of the page (and change the url so it looks like your changing the page).

Visit the page with an old browser. You will realise that the URL doesn't change or that a hash (#about.html) is used. That's because new browser support URL modification.

If you are programming by yourself, you will have to invest a lot of time to create a website like this...

Comment: Do you know if there is a tutorial or demo?

Comment: This one demo is ok: https://css-tricks.com/examples/AJAXReplaceSamePart/#index.php